# MongoDb- get length of array in updateMany (Node.js)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to do an update many.

The problem that I am encountering is getting the length of an array and seeing if it is less than or equal to another number being passed in from the params.

This is what I have done so far. But I feel this is a bad way of doing it. if anyone has a better way of doing it, please give your input. trying to improve :)

```
const updateStatus = (materialId, attempts) => {
  return db.collection.updateMany(
    {
      _id,
      [`data.${attempts}`]: { $exists: true },
      status: { $in: ['outstanding', 'overdue'] },
    },
    { status: 'restricted' }
  )
}
```

this is the data I am trying to update many on

```
[{
_id: 1,
status: 'outstanding',
data:[],
    },
    {
    _id: 2,
    status: 'overdue',
data:[{passed: true},{passed: false}],
    }
        {
        _id: 3,
        status: 'outstanding',
    data:[{passed: true},{passed: false}, {passed: false}],
        }
]
```

Comment: All i am doing is checking to see if it exists I was trying with the $size but it wasn't working for me sadly

Comment: What is `materialId` in the query?  What "logic" are you looking for using the size of `data` array? ... Perhaps something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dWOhgRcCNeB "Click me!")?

Comment: the materialId  is just a regular objectID. I am trying to figure out the length of the data.

Comment: Is the mongoplayground.net example close to what you are looking for?